# Motion Computing LE1600 touchscreen functions unavailable in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchscreen

I recently obtained a Motion Computing LE1600 that I replaced Windows XP with Ubuntu 14.04 on today, and I can not seem to get the touchscreen functions to work properly. Is there anything that can be done to rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem with 14.04LTS.  But I know that Ubuntu 12.04LTS DOES work with the LE1600 touchscreen.

So recently, I tried installing 12.04LTS and then immediately upgraded to 14.04LTS, and happily, this seems to work in terms of enabling the touchscreen.  I don't know about the reliability of this technique, but better than nothing.

If that isn't a satisfactory solution, in 12.04LTS, the touchscreen is detected as a Wacom tablet, so whatever the problem is, I would look there.